# Как сформировать новый массив объектов, сделав слияние по некоторому параметру?

Tags: javascript, lodash

хочу сформировать новый массив объектов из старого, используя js, возможно даже лучше lodash

у меня есть некоторая сущность:

```
const arr = [ 
{merch: 111, games: ['loto1', 'loto2']}, 
{merch: 111, games: ['loto2', 'loto3']}, 
{merch: 222, games: ['loto3', 'loto4']},
];
```

массив состоит из объектов, у них могут быть схожие значения в поле merch и общие значения в games
как сформировать новый массив, объединив в нем объекты по полю merch? при этом без дубликатов
на выходе хочу иметь подобное

```
=> [
{merch: 111, games: ['loto1', 'loto2', 'loto3']},
{merch: 222, games: ['loto3', 'loto4']},
]
```

пытался сделать через reduce из библиотеки lodash, но не до конца понимаю как это сделать

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Описание логики:

1. Начинаем с [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

   1. Результат будем записывать в словарик [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map). Можно заменить и на обычный объект, если надо, просто код, немного нагромоздится
   2. Смотрим, если у нас нет ключа `merch`, то просто записываем в словарик, новый ключ `merch` и значение набор [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) из `games`. Тут так же можно обойтись обычным объектом например, но опять таки это нагромоздит код
   3. Если есть такой ключ в словарике, то просто добавляем в набор все новые значения. Удобство `Set`-а в том, что он сам автоматически добавляет только уникальные значения
2. На выходе получаем `Map`, потому можем у него взять все наборы ключей-значений с помощью [entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/entries)
3. Получаем массив с помощью [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax), так же можно было воспользоваться и [Array.from()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)
4. Ну и самое простое, превращаем элементы массива в объекты нужного нам вида с помощью [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

   1. Так как в значениях словарика у нас хранились наборы, то преобразуем их обратно в массивы с помощью `spread`, так же можно было воспользоваться и `Array.from()`

Код:

```js
const arr = [{
    merch: 111,
    games: ['loto1', 'loto2']
  },
  {
    merch: 111,
    games: ['loto2', 'loto3']
  },
  {
    merch: 222,
    games: ['loto3', 'loto4']
  },
];

const uniqueArr = [...arr.reduce((result, el) => {

  if (!result.has(el.merch)) {
    return result.set(el.merch, new Set(el.games))
  }

  const merch = result.get(el.merch);

  for (const game of el.games) merch.add(game)

  return result;

}, new Map()).entries()].map(item => ({
  merch: item[0],
  games: [...item[1]]
}));

console.log(uniqueArr);
```